# Check installshield project without building

Tags: installshield

I have an installshield project that takes more then 6 minutes to build.
As this setup project is quite a mess I'm trying to clean it out a bit.
Currently I can see there are file references to files that are not available anymore.

How can I have installshield give me a list of errors without having to completely build the thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can click around the files and folders view looking for files that say 0 bytes.  You can also use release flags to create product configurations that only build select features.  But honestly 6 minutes isn't all that bad.  It'll be tough if you fix one thing at a time and rebuild over and over but if you can take your list of bugs and fix as many as you can you shouldn't have to build more then a few times.

Comment: There are several hundreds of subdirectories in varying degrees of nesting. Error listing doesn't show the missing files.
I did it anyway. More then an entire working day.